# Use variable as text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a video-playlist where the video scr is created in javascript:

```
video[0].src = video_url;
```

Now I want to use the variable "video_url" as my description text

```
<td id="description"></td>
```

So in html it should look like

```
<video src="video01.mov"></video>
<td id="description">video01.mov</td>
```

I tried to do this with the following code:

```
$('#description').append(video_url);
```

But now everytime I click on my next or previous button to load the next video jquery adds the next name to my td instead of just take the current src name:

```
<video src="video05.mov"></video>
<td id="description">video01.movvideo02.movvideo03.movvideo04.movvideo05.mov</td>
```

How is it possible that jquery uses only the CURRENT name of the src?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: `$('#description').text(video_url);`

Comment: use `text()` or `html()`. `append()` does append ! So adds to existing.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
$('#description').append(video_url);
```

Use:

```
$('#description').html(video_url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$('#description').append(video_url);
```

Try

```
$('#description').html(video_url);
```

OR

```
$('#description').text(video_url);
```

The Problem in your case is that `.append()` only append the values to existing value but you want to replace old value with new value.

Answer (score 0):

you are using id which is one time use so if you want to do anything dynamic user class and in click function write `$(this).find('your class name').html(video_url)` and then it will not add one after one .